# How to add extension methods to the Vector2 class in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, operator-overloading, extension-methods

I'm kinda struggeling with adding a nice extensionmethod for the Vector2 class in XNA.
I want to have a subtract method based on the input a vector2 and a float.

This is what i did already:

```
public static class Vector2Extensions
{
    public static Vector2 Subtract(Vector2 v1, float a)
    {
        return new Vector2(v1.X - a, v1.Y - a);
    }
}
```

Yet somehow when i want to call it like:

```
Vector2 x = Vector2.Subtract(new Vector2(2,0), 1.0f);
```

It doesn't seem to recognize my extension to the method (a 3rd overload as XNA has 2 overloads by default)

Another question, why can't i overload the - operator? (that's how i ended up in here)

Help would be lots appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one thing missing to make your method an extension method: the `this` keyword in the first argument, like so:

```
public static Vector2 Subtract(this Vector2 v1, float a)
```

Then you can use that method on an instance:

```
Vector2 x = new Vector2(2,0).Subtract(1.0f);
```

Or call it as a static method, but from your static class, not the "extended" class itself:

```
Vector2 x2 = Vector2Extensions.Subtract(new Vector2(2,0), 1.0f);
```

Operators can only be overloaded inside of a class in C#, not outside, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `this` keyword in your definition.

```
public static Vector2 Subtract(this Vector2 v1, float a)
{
    return new Vector2(v1.X - a, v1.Y - a);
}
```